# Prevent repeating tick labels in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to specify my own xtick labels in a plot.
The problem when going "the regular way" by defining `xticklabel={a1, a2, ...}` is that my whole label list is utilized and repeated at every xtick now, see image.

[image]

I can prevent this, when reading my labels from a file.
What am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
a  b  c  d  
0  5  3  4     
1  6  3  4   
2  7  3  4   
3  8  3  4   
4  9  3  4 
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{names.dat}
names
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xtick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    %xticklabels from table={names.dat}{names}, % this works
    xticklabel={a1, a2, a3, a4, a5},            % this does not
    ]
        \addplot table [x=a, y=b] {data.dat};
        \addplot table [x=a, y=c] {data.dat};
        \addplot table [x=a, y=d] {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xticklabel` specifies a single label for all ticks. In your MWE, `xticklabel={a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}` sets each label to `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5`. Replacing `xticklabel` with `xticklabels` gives the intended behavior.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
a  b  c  d  
0  5  3  4     
1  6  3  4   
2  7  3  4   
3  8  3  4   
4  9  3  4 
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{names.dat}
names
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xtick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    %xticklabels from table={names.dat}{names}, % this works
    xticklabels={a1, a2, a3, a4, a5},           % this works too
    %xticklabel={a1, a2, a3, a4, a5},           % this does not
    ]
        \addplot table [x=a, y=b] {data.dat};
        \addplot table [x=a, y=c] {data.dat};
        \addplot table [x=a, y=d] {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yapp, that did it. Thanks for pointing out the difference!